# Video in notification for Android

Tags: android

Can anyone please tell how to create a notification in android wherein I can play videos with an action buttons. Video should be shown playing in the notification. In the same way as a music player notification works but in this case video should be shown playing.

Comment: Hi. Did u find any official page about this?

Comment: Look at this straightforward, to the point answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38412767/8202132

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible with basic Android Notifications.

Comment: Hi. Do u know any official page which says this?