# play a small video in notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

Is there any way to play a small video in notification?  I searched in web and appears there isn't any solution . I can show picture or even play music in notification but not video. any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way to play a small video in notification?

No. Neither `SurfaceView` nor `TextureView` are eligible widgets for a `RemoteViews`, let alone things layered on top of them (e.g., `VideoView`).